# Can the user be forced to enter a non-initial value by the Table Maintenance screen in SM30?

Tags: abap, sap-basis, sap-data-dictionary

I'd like to force the user to chose between `Yes` and `No`, and not let him add an entry where the value is initial.

[image]

This is regardless of whether I check the `Initial` checkbox in the table definition.

Can this be done?

Domain data type : CHAR, 1 character, no conversion routine.
Value range: single values:
'1' description = 'Yes'
'2' description = 'No'

Comment: Could you please add information about the domain, its fixed values and the attributes of the screen field?

Comment: what do you mean by the attributes of the screen field? that's the standard transaction SM30, the properties are the standard properties indicating my domain. Should I include some pictures regardless? i mean there isn't really much to see except for what i've written in the EDIT section

Comment: Have you tried to edit the screen and set the field to mandatory?

Comment: That worked. I assumed the generated function modules are not to be changed, but it seems as though that's what they're for. You can turn your comment into an answer if you want the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the screen and set the field to mandatory. Be aware that you will loose the change if the screen is re-generated.

Answer (score 3):

**By far the easiest way is to use a data element in the table that only allows non-initial values.**

If you can't change the data element, you can try using table maintenance events in the table maintenance generator:

[image]

You may be able to use event 1 (Before save) or event 5 to build a manual check, but 5 does not kick off on change.

[image]

If that doesn't work, you can still manually add a check in the PAI of the screen, however you run the risk that if someone regenerates the maintenance scree, they will forget/not know to put the check back in.

You can set the compare flag:

[image]

But from what I've seen the flag doesn't actually force you to redo any of the changes, and is still pretty easy to miss.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with that steps:

1. in SE11 choose the **Utilities** menu -> **Table Maintenance Generator**
2. in the Table Maintenance Generator go to menu **Environment** -> **Modification** -> **Maintenance Screens**, then select the screen (usually is 0001), in the Element List Tab you find the **Special attr**, in the field Input, you choose **Required** for the field you want obligatory.

Thanks.

Regards.
Gil Mota.